# Can I ask about Mathics3 here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I stumbled upon [Mathics3](https://mathics.org), a free and open-source clone of Mathematica.

It seems to share most of the basic syntax/functions with Mathematica, though I assume some advanced features are not implemented.

So far the Mathematica documentation was helpful for learning Mathics3.

Can I ask about Mathics3 on this site? Assuming I'm interested only in the common subset of it and Mathematica (though I have no way to confirm what exactly is the common subset, not having a Mathematica license).

Comment: Previous [discussion re: mathics](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/include-questions-on-open-source-variants-of-mathematica-in-mathematica-se)

Comment: there is special forum for mathics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathics

Comment: @Nasser There were only two questions this year, one of which seems to have been tagged `mathics` by mistake. :( I think I'll get better answers asking here, if as rm-rf's link implies it's allowed.